# How to avoid data caching when querying the database?

Tags: sql-server-2008, entity-framework, caching, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm having a strange problem with ASP.NET MVC4 and Entity Framework 5: The web application I'm building retrieves data from a database and sends it as Json into a viewmodel on the page, from which it then gets presented in a table on the page. The data represents the state of some datapoints that change every now and then.

Now I observed the following behaviour:

- when I run the web application from my development server, everything works fine and the shown data is up to date.
- when I deploy the web app to a production server (which talks to the very same DB), the page does not represent the current state of the data

I can't breakpoint the controller method that retrieves the data, as it only occurs on the production server, but when I look into the Json data I can see that it actually is old data. So it seems like EF is caching the retrieved data. This is a serious problem as we use this web application for industrial monitoring purposes and therefore need to rely on up-to-date data.

Has anyone encountered the same issue? Any help on this is greatly appreciated!

Comment: If you are calling this via a get with ajax using jquery, then be sure to add $.ajaxSetup({cache:false}}); to your page

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I'll better include that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know entity framework that well but I think this has something to do with change tracking. I'd try disabling it to force EF to re-query the DB, I think (and others please can correct me if I'm wrong) but unless SaveChanges has been called on an ObjectContext if you re-query the same data the database won't be queried again.

I've used `MergeOption = MergeOption.NoTracking` (on the ObjectSet) to turn it off in my project.

Comment: Thanks, that did the job! Caching/object tracking is usually a good idea, but here the data in the DB gets changed from other applications. Data consistence is way more important than performance in my case.